# SQL query giving empty result

Tags: sql, sql-view

I am CASTING column values from string to decimal in SQL and using it for comparison and creating a view out of it. But when converting these values from string to decimal, it is returning an empty SQL result.

The query is like this-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[2yrAlerts_and_Warnings]
AS (
SELECT        
h.region, h.plant, t.assets, t.Types, t.machineID, 
cast (VibrationArms as decimal) as Vibration_Arms,
cast (VibrationVrms as decimal) as Vibration_Vrms,
cast (VibrationPeak as decimal) as Vibration_Peak,
cast (VibrationDKW as decimal) as Vibration_DKW,
cast (PerformanceCurrent as decimal) as Performance_Current,
cast (PerformanceSpeed as decimal) as Performance_Speed,
cast (PerformancePower as decimal) as Performance_Power,
cast (StatEnergy as decimal) as Stat_Energy,

t.VibrationArms,
220 AS Vibration_Arms_Threshold,
(CASE WHEN VibrationArms >= 220 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vibration_Arms_Alert,
(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN VibrationArms >= 220 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'There is an alert because value of Arms output of vibration sensor is more than 250 ' ELSE 'No Alerts' END) AS Vibration_Arms_Alert_Remarks,
(CASE WHEN VibrationArms BETWEEN 210 AND 220  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vibration_Arms_Warning,
(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN VibrationArms BETWEEN 210 AND 220  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'There is a warning because value of Arms output of vibration sensor lies between 240 and 250 ' ELSE 'No Warnings' END) AS Vibration_Arms_Warning_Remarks,
(CASE WHEN VibrationArms > 230 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CRITICAL_ALERT_Vibration_Arms,

t.timess, 
DATEPART(year, t.timess) AS Year, 
DATEPART(Month, t.timess) AS Month, 
DATEPART(WEEK, t.timess) AS Week, 
DATEPART(Day, t.timess)AS Day, 
DATEPART(Hour, t.timess) AS Hour
FROM            dbo.oneyeardata1hr AS t INNER JOIN
                         dbo.asset_hierarchy_new AS h ON h.Asset = t.assets
                         );
GO
```

This is giving an empty result like this-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The creation of a view does not return rows, you should execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[2yrAlerts_and_Warnings]
```

If the above is not returning rows, the issue is not in your conversion but here:

```
FROM dbo.oneyeardata1hr AS t 
INNER JOIN dbo.asset_hierarchy_new AS h 
   ON h.Asset = t.assets
```

Change the join to `LEFT` - there must be something wrong with your criteria.

Comment: I already did the first part in a separate query but still it is giving error. As you can see in image, error is `query completed with errors`. For second part, I used `LEFT` join too but same issue.

Comment: @PeakyBlinder Try commenting each row till getting  the error one. I guess you are not able to convert some value.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute below query to give result.

select * from [dbo].[2yrAlerts_and_Warnings];

Comment: I already did that in a separate query but still it is giving error. As you can see in image, error is `query completed with errors`

Comment: @PeakyBlinder,Try after commenting each row and execute it one by one.There should be any query error or conversion error.